How to find previous and next strings from a list of (double, string), given a double?
Given a list of (doubles, string values and Boolean flags). I would like to create a function that takes a double and the given list, and returns the 2 values nearest to (either side of) that double where flag is true.
This is probably best shown with a code example. I've changed to not use models to avoid having to paste lots of code.
It always needs to return either the first 2 or last 2 if the given double is outside the range so it should never fail.
        [TestMethod]
        public void FindNearestDoubles_GivenDouble_ShouldReturnNearestValue()
        {
            var listOfDoubleValues = new List<(double time, string value, bool flag)>
            {
                (1, "test1", true),
                (3, "test2", true),
                (5, "test3", true),
                (9, "test4", false),
                (78, "test5", true)
            };

            var testDataWithExpectedValues = new List<(double value, string expectedPrevValue, string expectedNextValue)>
            {
                (1, "test1", "test2"),
                (2, "test1", "test2"),
                (3, "test1", "test3"),
                (6, "test3", "test5"),
                (-50, "test1", "test2"),
                (77, "test3", "test5"),
                (800, "test3", "test5"),
            };

            testDataWithExpectedValues.ForEach(_ =>
            {
                var closetValues = FindClosestValues(_.value, listOfDoubleValues);
                Assert.AreEqual(_.expectedPrevValue, closetValues.prevValue);
                Assert.AreEqual(_.expectedNextValue, closetValues.nextValue);

            });
        }

        // does not currently work
        private (string prevValue, string nextValue) FindClosestValues(double valueToFind, IList<(double time, string value, bool flag)> values)
        {
            string prevValue = values.First().value;
            string nextValue = values.Last().value;

            foreach (var value in values.Where(_ => _.flag == true))
            {
                if (valueToFind > value.time)
                    prevValue = values.Single(_ => _.time == valueToFind).value;

                if (valueToFind < value.time)
                    nextValue = values.Single(_ => _.time == valueToFind).value;
            }

            return (prevValue, nextValue);
        }


So it seems like you want to ignore anything that is equal to the value to find? Can we assume that there will be at least two elements in the list that is not equal to the value to find? Otherwise, please explain what the method should return in that case.

If the value is equal it needs to return the 2 doubles either side of it (e.g. in testData where the value is 3). The list will always contains more than 2 items.

This would be easier if you can sort the list by value first. Is this an option?

Could this be a Dictionary<double, (string, bool)> or is 'time' not always unique?

yes they will be sortable actually

Possibly could be Dictionary<double, (string, bool)> but would prefer not as would mean altering some other code (as this is actually a model used elsewhere)

Why are you using double when all your values are integers?

this is just test data, they can be doubles

How would a Dictionary help? I don't think so. Depending on usage statistics, I'd go for a sorted Datastructure - maybe some sort of Tree ...

Why output for 1 is "test1", "test2" not "test2", "test3"?

If the input is already sorted, I would go for Array.BinarySearch with a custom comparer to get the index where the searched value is found or - if not found - where it would be in the sort order (as bitwise complement).

As far as I can see, we want to find a fork for a given value target; having a sequence (let it be ints for simplicity)
1 2 3 5 9 78

we want to find largest possible value (left) which is less than target and smallest possible value (right) which is greater than target.
For instance, for target == 5 we should return 3 and 9 (note, that 5 itself can't be left or right)
  3 < 5 < 9

We have two degenerated cases

When target is less or equal than any value, return two smallest values which are not equal to target
When target is greater or equal than any value, return two greatest values which are not equal to target

For instance, we return 1 and 2 for 0 and 5 and 9 for 78
If it's your case than here is the implementation:
public static (T? left, T? right) Fork<T>(IEnumerable<T?> source, 
                                          T? target, 
                                          IComparer<T>? comparer = default) {
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

  comparer ??= Comparer<T>.Default;

  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(comparer);

  T? left = default;
  T? secondLeft = default;
  T? right = default;
  T? secondRight = default;

  var hasLeft = false;
  var hasSecondLeft = false;
  var hasRight = false;
  var hasSecondRight = false;

  foreach (var item in source) {
    var compare = comparer.Compare(item, target);

    if (compare > 0) {
      if (!hasRight || comparer.Compare(item, right) <= 0) {
        (hasSecondRight, hasRight) = (hasRight, true);
        (secondRight, right) = (right, item);
      }
      else if (!hasSecondRight || comparer.Compare(item, secondRight) <= 0) {
        hasSecondRight = true;
        secondRight = item;
      }
    }
    else if (compare < 0) {
      if (!hasLeft || comparer.Compare(item, left) >= 0) {
        (hasSecondLeft, hasLeft) = (hasLeft, true);
        (secondLeft, left) = (left, item);
      }
      else if (!hasSecondLeft || comparer.Compare(item, secondLeft) <= 0) {
        hasSecondLeft = true;
        secondLeft = item;
      }
    }
  }

  return hasLeft && hasRight ? (left, right)
    : hasLeft ? (secondLeft, left)
    : (right, secondRight);
}

Then you can use it as follow:
private static (string prevValue, string nextValue) FindClosestValues(double valueToFind,
    IEnumerable<(double time, string value, bool flag)> values)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<(double time, string value, bool flag)>
        .Create((left, right) => left.time.CompareTo(right.time));

    var result = Fork(values.Where(item => item.flag), (valueToFind, "", true), comparer);

    return (result.left.Item2, result.right.Item2);
}

Demo:
var testDataWithExpectedValues = new List<(double value, string expectedPrevValue, string expectedNextValue)>
{
    (1, "test1", "test2"),
    (2, "test1", "test2"),
    (3, "test1", "test3"),
    (6, "test3", "test5"),
    (-50, "test1", "test2"),
    (77, "test3", "test5"),
    (800, "test3", "test5"),
};

var actual = testDataWithExpectedValues
    .Select(item => $"{item.value, 3} : {FindClosestValues(item.value, listOfDoubleValues)} expected ({item.expectedPrevValue}, {item.expectedNextValue})");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, actual));

Output:
  1 : (test2, test3) expected (test1, test2) // <- Note that "1" is not within the fork
  2 : (test1, test2) expected (test1, test2)
  3 : (test1, test3) expected (test1, test3)
  6 : (test3, test5) expected (test3, test5)
-50 : (test1, test2) expected (test1, test2)
 77 : (test3, test5) expected (test3, test5)
800 : (test3, test5) expected (test3, test5)

Fiddle

Your example is a bit complicated, you can simplify it into a list of only 3 elements, and the problem can be simplified into 7 situations:



Situation
Expectation
SSEB*




[]xyz
x,y
___x


[x]yz
x,y
__xy


x[]yz
x,y
_x_y


x[y]z
x,z
_xyz


xy[]z
y,z
xy_z


xy[z]
y,z
xyz_


xyz[]
y,z
yz__



x,y,z represents the values, [] represents the position of the search value
SSEB is an abbreviation I invented to represent two values that are smaller than the search value, one value equal to the search value, and one value bigger than the search value. They can be solved through the following code:
string smaller1 = null, smaller2 = null, equal = null, bigger = null;
var itor = values.Where(v => v.flag);
foreach(var v in itor)
{
    if(v.time < valueToFind)
    {
        smaller1 = smaller2;
        smaller2 = v.value;
    }
    else if(v.time == valueToFind)
    {
        equal = v.value;
    }
    else if(v.time > valueToFind)
    {
        bigger = v.value;
        break;
    }
}

After obtaining these four, return different combinations based on the above situations:
if(bigger == null)
    return equal == null ? (smaller1, smaller2) : (smaller2, equal);
else if(smaller2 != null)
    return  (smaller2, bigger);
else if(equal != null)
    return (equal, bigger);
else
    return (bigger, itor.ElementAt(1).value);

